# Update database with nested transactions scope

Tags: c#, database, transactionscope

In my application I have two methods: `GetPaymentToDate` and `RemovePayment`:

```
public Payment RemovePayment(int paymentId)
{
    Payment payment;
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
        new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
    {
        //some staff
        m_staffContext.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
    return payment;
}

public Payment GetPaymentToDate(DateTime paymentDate)
{
    var payment = new Payment
    {
        //initialize properties
    };
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
        new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
    {
        m_staffContext.Payments.Add(payment);
        m_staffContext.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
    return payment;
}
```

No I need to implement *Update* method. The logic of this method is remove the old one and then create a new payment. So I want to do it in one parent transaction scope and role back nested transaction if the another is failed. I'm going to delete `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` option from existing methods and in update method write something like this:

```
public Payment UpdatePayment(int paymentId)
{
    Payment newPayment;
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
        new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
    {
        var removedPayment = RemovePayment(paymentId);
        var newPayment = GetPaymentToDate(removedPayment.Date);
        m_staffContext.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
    return newPayment;        
}
```

Am I correct with my code?

Comment: Why do you have `RequiresNew` with every transactionscope? The default value is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call the methods but implement the actual logic in Update Payment in using block like:

```
using( var transaction = .....)
{
   var payment = m_staffContext.Payments.Get(paymentId);
   m_staffContext.Payments.Remove(payment);
   m_staffContext.Payments.Add(payment);
   m_staffContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But why are you not updating the existing payment only.
In AddNewPayment method, initialization of Payment object can be done in separate method to be reused.

Please comment if this doesn't solve your problem.